# Can I use 现代汉语词典 outside of the paper dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, software

现代汉语词典 seems to be the de facto standard for Chinese dictionaries. Some users here use it as well. But it seems only possible for the paper version.

But I might miss something. Is it possible to use it outside of its paper version, such as online or app? I searched for it on the App Store, but seems that there are too many results and I don't know which is the correct one (actually all of them don't seem to be official ones...). Also I really hate it if I purchase an app but later found some words are missing.

Or is it only available on the paper-version?

Comment: @Blaszard I saw someone mentioned Pleco below, on their products list you can see they have https://store.pleco.com/products.php?ios=1 
`Xiandai Hanyu Guifan Cidian - $29.99
Chinese-Chinese dictionary with 71,000 entries, featuring detailed / explanation-rich definitions; recommended only for advanced students.` and `Xiandai Hanyu Dacidian - $19.99 (version 3 only)
Chinese-Chinese dictionary with 110k entries`. I can tell you I bought *Guifan* when the second edition was out, when the third edition came out Pleco updated it for free without any extra fees.

Comment: Don't need to chase it. It's not considered as standard. China government do has a standard for Characters (both simplified and traditional) in PDF, but not for words. Chasing local government language standards doesn't have too much meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy it as an in-app purchase in the Pleco app. It costs 19.99 USD at the moment. For Android devices and also for iPhone /iPad. Reference: http://www.pleco.com/products/pleco-for-iphone-ipad/pricing-bundles/ in the section "Individual Add-ons /dictionaries ". If you install Pleco for free with just the 现代汉语词典 as an extra it should just cost 19.99 USD.

Answer (score 0):

[《现代汉语规范词典》和《现代汉语词典》相比各自有何特色？ - Dictionaryphile的回答 - 知乎](https://www.zhihu.com/question/20259584/answer/138804468) under ##电子版本 you can find various licensed online/electronic version. Specifically, this one seems to be<sup>[1]</sup> from the publisher 商务印书馆: http://www.icidian.com.cn/cpnet/ but requires login. And I cannot find anywhere to register/purchase. So I can't tell if it is working/genuine or not.

[1]: The ICP备案号 from the website, 京ICP备 05007371号-13 does not exist in [工业和信息化产业部 ICP/IP/域名信息备案管理系统](http://www.miibeian.gov.cn/publish/query/indexFirst.action). However, 京ICP备 05007371号 does exist and shows multiple sub-records all belonging to 商务印书馆有限公司. WHOIS information from CNNIC also indicates the registrant to be 商务印书馆有限公司.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the app:
like:
[image]
1.现代汉语词典 2.百度汉语词典 3.汉语词典2016 4.有道语文达人
or the pleco http://www.pleco.com/

> it come from: https://www.zhihu.com/question/35136488

the online website:
you can use it 
http://xh.5156edu.com (Is very clear and ample.)

Comment: Yes I read the answer as well, but my question is not about which dictionary is the best but *can I use the 现代汉语词典 in non-paper version as well?". The first app calls itself as such but does this cover the same as what the paper-version offers?

Comment: yes，it is same.and it can renew as well ,but the noise is  it has some ads,and i don't know the iphone american market has the same, i live  in china

Comment: besides the 现代汉语词典，the 新华字典 is the best , when we are yong ,every family has it,just like the Bible in american family

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: Do not believe the App Store.**
I looked up 现代汉语词典 in the Commercial Press's homepage, and only found it available in hard copy. The Commercial Press also publishes apps, but as you can see, it doesn't develop one for 现代汉语词典.
Link: http://www.cp.com.cn/digital/app.html

Answer (score -2):

You can also try Baidu's online dictionary: 
http://dict.baidu.com

Comment: Welcome! The OP is asking for an *authoritative* dictionary. Could you improve your answer by adding what would you say that makes Baidu's online dictionary authoritative?