# Dictionary for different dialects

Tags: pronunciation, pinyin, taiwan, mainland-china

I am in search for a dictionary that have the most common Chinese words mapped with a one-to-one relationship for different dialects. To be specific, I am looking for a entries mapped for Taiwan (Chinese), Standard Mainland (Chinese), and what seems to be Beijing (Chinese). But more dialects would be appreciated.

For instance, when looking up the word "不客气" (and with traditional: 不客氣), I receive the following alternatives (notice the pinyin tones differences):

| Dialect | Pinyin | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Taiwan | bú kè qì (**bu2** ke4 qi4) | [moedict.tw](https://www.moedict.tw/%7E%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%A2%E6%B0%A3) |
| Standard Mainland | bù kè qì (bu4 ke4 qi4) | [moedict.tw](https://www.moedict.tw/%7E%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%A2%E6%B0%A3) |
| Beijing? | bù kè qi (bu4 ke4 **qi5**) | [youdao.com](https://www.youdao.com/w/eng/%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%A2%E6%B0%A3/#keyfrom=dict2.index) |

I have found a dictionary that can map out the Taiwan and Beijing(?) dialect as the example above (moedict). However, moedict only have the Taiwan and Standard Mainland. If I had either a Standard Mainland<>Beijing or Taiwan<>Beijing then I could merge. But I have not found such a dictionary yet.

I also would like to find a dictionary that have the word changes, like 这里 (zhe4 li3) <> 这儿 (zhe4 er5).

Is there any dictionary online that consists of such entries and relationships?

Comment: Why would Standard Mainland/Beijing pronounce 不 in the fourth tone??

Comment: Axel, I think you're missing an important piece of info: many dictionaries do not write out the tone sandhi. 不+{4th tone} is bu2, but many dictionaries just write out bu4. Similarly for chained 3rd tones.

Answer (score 1):

You may try Chinese Wiktionary and English Wiktionary, each has its own merits.
https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%A2%E6%B0%94
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%A2%E6%B0%A3#Chinese

When searching for the pronunciation of a specific dialect word (since it may not be listed in Wiktionary) you can try 现代汉语方言大词典 of 古音小镜:
http://www.guguolin.com/book_fangyandacidian.php
The standard dictionary of Mainland Mandarin, 现代汉语词典 has mobile Apps ([Can I use 现代汉语词典 outside of the paper dictionary?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/can-i-use-%E7%8E%B0%E4%BB%A3%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8-outside-of-the-paper-dictionary)). You can use it to check standard Mainland pronunciation. However it is not free to wield its full strength.

In fact, Mainland Mandarin and Taiwanese Mandarin differ little in pronunciation. The main pronunciation differences are in certain characters, for example the conjunction  和 hé/hàn. In your case, it is only that the tone sandhi is not marked in the dictionary that makes 不 of 不客气 seem to be bù in Mainland Mandarin. The actual pronunciation of 不客气 is bú kè qi (气 here is 5th tone according to 现代汉语词典, the 客气 entry). You can learn the tone sandhi rules, especially the 一不七八 rules here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese_phonology#Tone_sandhi.

The terminological differences are more evident. 中华语文知识库 is a dictionary compiled by experts from both Mainland China and Taiwan, aimed at collecting such differences in Chinese words. You can get access to it here : http://www.chinese-linguipedia.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Pleco has two separate dictionaries for Mandarin-Cantonese translations, some soley for character pronunciation and some for actual dictionary entries. There is also a Cross Straits add on for dictionary entries comparing Mainland Chinese and Taiwanese Chinese.

[image]